# tkz Axe with degree symbol

Tags: tkz-euclide, tkz-collection, tkz-fct

Is it possible to get an Axe with individual x-steps having the degree symbol? Like `$50^\circ$, $100^\circ$` etc.?

```
   \documentclass{scrartcl}
   \usepackage{pgf,tikz,tkz-fct,tkz-euclide}
   \usetkzobj{all}
   \begin{document}
         \begin{tikzpicture}
         \tkzInit[xmin=0,xmax=370,ymin=-1,ymax=1,xstep=60,ystep=0.5]
         \tkzGrid[color = gray!50!white,sub,subxstep=15,subystep=0.1]
         \tkzAxeX[right space=0.2, label=$\alpha$]
         \tkzAxeY
         \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: pgf and tikz are loaded by tkz's packages

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the graduations by yourself. 
`\tkzDrawAxe` draws the axe then you can add the graduation without the symbol and you can put the symbol at the end of the axe with the label.
Another possibility is to rewrite the command `\tkzLabelX` but this macro is long.
perhaps you can in this case write your own macro. I think it's perhaps the best solution.